Wifi will not stay on
I have a Rpi 5 4GB running Ubuntu. The WiFi works well on other devices, so it is not the WiFi. My Rpi still does not maintain a consistent connection when connected to Hotspot. This has been going on for a while now,
Thanks in Advance,
ArchedPCs
